# Dart split integer and add their values

Tags: flutter, dart

Suppose I have a variable int a = 12345, I want to split a to [1,2,3,4,5] and add them like [1+2+3+4+5] and in final I want to get a result of a = 15 how can I achieve this?

Comment: This is a coding problem and its done with adding mod 10 recursively. u dont need the second array, will add the answer in a few mins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All u have to do is recursively add every digit individually.

```
void main() {
  
  int a = 12345; 
  int sum = 0; 
  while(a>0){
      sum  = sum + (a%10); 
      a = (a/10).floor(); 
  }  
  print(sum);
  //if u want to store in a 
  a = sum;
}
```

Comment: let me try and test it I will post the result

Comment: I am getting 0 in a result

Comment: That's strange i'm getting 15

Answer (score 2):

**There are different ways to achieve the same, one of the ways is as:**

```
void main() {
  int num = 12345;
  int sum = 0;
  
  String numAsString = num.toString();

  for (int i = 0; i < numAsString.length; i++) {
    sum += int.parse(numAsString[i]);
  }
  
  print(sum); // 15
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve using the split() as

```
void main(){
  var i=34567;
  var iStr=i.toString().split('');
  var exp= iStr.join('+');
  var sum=iStr.fold(0,(a,b)=>int.parse(a.toString())+int.parse(b));
  print(exp);
  print(sum);  
}
```

Output:
3+4+5+6+7
25
If you need only the sum of the integer then

```
void main() {
  var i = 34567;
  var iStr = i.toString().split('');
  var sum = iStr.fold(0, (a, b) => int.parse(a.toString()) + int.parse(b));
  print(sum);
}
```

Comment: let me try and test it I will post the result

Answer (score 1):

I would approach it by first converting the integer to a String.
Then mapping each single character into an int and finally simply
reduce the iterator of ints into the sum.

```
int num = 12345;
  print(num
    .toString()
    .split('')
    .map(
      (c) =>int.parse(c)
    ).reduce((a,b) => a+b));
```